# Instantiating TypedDict easily with unpacked args

Tags: python, types, python-typing

When using `NamedTuple`, you can easily instantiate by unpacking an arbitrary number of arguments using `*`

```py
class DateTimeUTC(NamedTuple):
    year: int
    month: int
    day: int
    hour: int
    minute: int
    second: float

dt = DateTimeUTC(*time.gmtime(1639480335.751329)[:6])
```

I'd prefer to reprsent it as a dictionary using `TypedDict` instead of a tuple, but I'm not able to easily unpack arguments in the same fashion.

```py
class DateTimeUTC(TypedDict):
    year: int
    month: int
    day: int
    hour: int
    minute: int
    second: float

dt = DateTimeUTC(*time.gmtime(1639480335.751329)[:6]) # <-- this breaks
```

I get the following error

`Expected 0 positional arguments Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)`

[image]

I seen that I can do this

```py
Y, M, D, h, m, s = time.gmtime(1639480335.751329)[:6]
dt = DateTimeUTC(year=Y, month=M, day=D, hour=h, minute=m, second=s)
```

but it's not as elegant as I'd like.

I tried implementing a custom `__init__()` constructor on the class, but that is apparently not allowed either.

`TypedDict classes can contain only type annotations Pylance`

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: `TypedDict`s are basically `dict`s with type annotations, and `dict`s are totally different from `tuple`s

Comment: No, a typed dict **is just a wrapper for the purposes of static analysis** (because many people use `dict` objects not as arbitrary mapping types but as record types). It creates just a regular `dict`. The "class" you have basically forwards its arguments to the `dict` constructor.

Comment: So, just write a helper function if it is something you don't want to write out manually a lot

Comment: FYI, you can get a dict from the `NameTuple` instance with its `_asdict` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible workarounds:

1. Use the `NamedTuple`, and get a corresponding `dict` when necessary.

   ```
   class DateTimeUTC(NamedTuple):
       ...

   dt = DateTimeUTC(*time.gmtime(1639480335.751329)[:6])

   assert dt._asdict() == {'year': 2021, 'month': 12, 'day': 14, 'hour': 11, 'minute': 12, 'second': 15}
   ```
2. Define the `TypedDict`, and use its `__annotations__` attribute to construct an instance.

   ```
    class DateTimeUTC(TypedDict):
        ...

    dt = DateTimeUTC(zip(DateTimeUTC.__annotations__,
                         time.gmtime(1639480335.751329)[:6]))
   ```